# Related Accounts: textual list with icons -- vs -- only icons?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, association

Find it rare that I'm able to make an interface suggestion and know that I'm right, but in this case I'll venture out on a limb -- and say I am.

**Why on the "Related Accounts" tab are the textual names for the sites not listed?**

Guessing it should look like the listing on the home page of [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/questions) under "Top Network Sites" -- all I know is that every time I go to the "Related Accounts" page I look, and look, and look... :-) ...Trying to recall/find the icon for the site I'm looking for.

EDIT: Here's another example of the sites listed... https://stackexchange.com/sites

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The associations tab now gets information directly from http://stackexchange.com and has a simpler, textual display sorted by rep.

Comment: Wow, much better, thank you for the modification. The stackexchange platform of sites ROCK, it's an amazing way to share information. Best wishes to you, and all that are part of stackexchange. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

So, turns out there's already a page that look almost like what I'm talking about, but it's only on ONE of the account pages of all the sites. Here's how to find it:

1. Go to http://stackexchange.com
2. Then view your own user page
3. Then click your accounts tab

This page is a HUGE improvement over the rest of the account page views on the other Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is simply that the associated accounts page shows the flair, and the flair, by design, does not include the site name.

Modifying the flair is not optimal, as it's meant to be small.

I suggest that the site name (linked) be placed above each flair.

Comment: I'm not sure what "now that many sites share the same icons" is about -- no sites have the same icon

Comment: @Pollyanna: All I personally care about is what site's I'm a member of, and those that I'm not... maybe even with an option to hide them. Other meta-data is nice, but that's not what I view an "Accounts" page as.

Comment: @Michael - Huh, it wasn't long ago that they did have the generic blue B on graph paper icon, but I see that now they are different.

Comment: @Michael yeah I don't think any have the same icon, but at the resolution in question a lot of the beta site icons don't really stick out distinctly

Comment: @Daniel Solution: Assign a different gravatar for each site. Then it's a much bigger picture that makes it far easier to identify which site is which. ♪

Comment: @All: How do you feel about the new layout of the accounts page? -- (@Michael Mrozek, @Adam Davis, @Daniel DiPaolo, @Grace Note)

Comment: @blunders It's nice.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a matter of space, I think.  I have over a dozen related accounts and it would make the page much larger to have the full text name of each site.  A tooltip for each site would be a nice addition, though you can hover over the account block and see the URL (as a bit of a workaround).

Comment: @Daniel DiPaolo: The current layout takes up more screen space than just the names alone do on the home page of stackexchange.com under "Top Network Sites"

Comment: @blunders Well, the current layout also shows considerably more information than the "Top Network Sites" box

Comment: @Michael Mrozek: True, but I care more about using the sites - than meta-data that's not clearly tied to the source; meaning it's just a bunch of random small icons to me with data next to them. Thanks for point that out though!

Comment: @blunders If you're just trying to get to the sites and don't care about the other info on the accounts page, use the text links in the page footer

Comment: @Michael Mrozek: Thanks for the suggestion, but those don't include the beta sites... :-) ...just checked, since I hadn't even noticed the links in the footer; which would be of help in some cases clearly.

Comment: @blunders There's two footers, as it were. One for the Beta sites, which lists all of the Beta sites but none of the graduated, and the one which doesn't list the Beta sites. So, indeed, there is a break between them, but a faster method than using your profile to transition between the two "regions" is to use the Stack Exchange dropdown in the top left corner - its site list would be faster to use than to click your profile, then your accounts tab. And, as an added bonus, it includes text.

Comment: @Grace Good call; I forgot the footers are divided (I have a userscript that shows all of them on all sites). The SE dropdown is a great idea, that's probably the best way

Comment: @Grace Note: Again, thanks for the suggestion; I've in fact seen both the footer and the "All Sites" tab on the dropdown on the top left. I'd much rather load a full page an be able to press CTRL+F "webm"+ENTER and find webmaster than see a list of "All Sites" -- again, there may be faster was to do XYZ, but there's a page called "My Accounts" which is not functioning as I'd expect it to. Me making a request to change the navigation system for the site is a request, I'm pointing out what I view as a rendering bug.

Comment: @blunders I'm not giving any statement as to the functionality of the associated accounts page (It's fine for me, but one can easily see why) - otherwise I'd be posting as an answer. I'm just giving you an example of something that can work. Whether it merely tides you over until this gets changed, or if that just becomes your onwards form of transportation, it's still a helpful option to have.

Comment: @blunders My point is there's like 17 different ways to do what you're trying to do; the footer, the "all sites" list in the drop down, the [list of SE sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites) (which is even filterable, so you could type "webm" in the box). I'd prefer that we not change the only page that shows your current account info on every site to be a duplicate of all those other places -- you're trying to use the accounts tab for the wrong thing

Comment: @Michael Mrozek: It's an accounts page that allows you to manage your accounts, that's it function -- the point of the page may also be to view something else, but... to manage your accounts, you've got to be able to see them -- which is currently not the case; currently you see an icon for an account, instead of the name of the account. Personally, I care more about using the sites, than how much rep, flair, badges, etc. I have on a given account; which may be what people use it for, but that's not it's function; IMHO.

Comment: @Grace Note: Thanks, I agree - my solution is just to bookmark my account in a folder.